# Unable to use native Windows library in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows-runtime, windows-10, electron, node-gyp

I am trying to write a simple [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app that uses Windows native notifications. For this use I depend on [electron-windows-interactive-notifications](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-interactive-notifications).

When I run `npm install` and after that `electron-rebuild` on my project I get:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\moro\projects\tw-en-ty\node_modules\electron-windows-interactive-notifications\build\Release\notifications_bindings.node
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:583:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (C:\Users\moro\projects\tw-en-ty\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
```

According to a [NodeJS issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2964) it can be a native dependency problem. When I examine `notifications_bindings.node` by [dependencywalker](http://dependencywalker.com/) I see following missing direct DLLs (among many missing nested):

[image]

Frankly I have no idea what the problem is:

- wrong usage of [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)?
- wrong usage of [electron-windows-interactive-notifications](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-interactive-notifications)?
- problem in [NodeRT](https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT)?
- problem in [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)?
- problem in my environment?

Can you help me move a step closer to the problem resolution?

Thank you very much!

> Question was also asked [here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-interactive-notifications/issues/4)

Comment: It looks like you're missing node.dll and interactivenotifications.dll (to say the least). Are they present aside your main .exe file (electron.exe or something else)

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for the response. Well, when I search for missing .dlls I see them on following places: 

**node.dll** - `node_modules\electron\dist\ `;
**interactivenotifications.dll** - `node_modules\electron-windows-interactive-notifications\Release\ `;
**api-...-.dll** - `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x64\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll `;

I would say they need to be relatively or absolutely referenced the same way as the correct kernel32.dll or ole32.dll

Comment: you should just copy them in the same dir as the main exe (electron.exe or other if you renamed it). You don't need to put them in \windows\system32

Comment: @SimonMourier - after copying them, there is a new error raised: `App threw an error during load Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` After resolving this by substituting some 32bit dependencies with 64bit ones, I get `A dynamic link library initialization routine failed.` I think that this whole path of step-by-step hacks is a dead end. I wish the library creator would take a look at this.

Comment: @MartinD did you figure it out? Having the same issue...

Comment: @stoefln unfortunately no, I had to abandon the project I was building as I couldn't get past the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

- Install MS Visual Studio first.
- `npm install --global windows-build-tools` run as Administrator
- Run electron rebuild `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`

Alternate method:

- `cd node_modules\electron-windows-interactive-notifications`
- `node-gyp rebuild --target=1.8.4 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron` where 1.8.4 is electron version